# SQL Server Transaction Log keeps growing with simple recovery model

Tags: sql-server, logging, transactions

I have a database against which there are very frequent inserts and deletes (but not in bulk). It is set to simple recovery. The total actual space occupied by the DB within its mdf files is around 1GB, and the total space taken by the log file within the ldf is around 600GB after 2 weeks.

Given the following:
- Simple recovery model
- No replication
- No long running transactions (average is 5s per transaction)
- Daily backups
- Daily index rebuilding

My questions are:

1. Why does it get so big?
2. Why doesn't it get empty?
3. How can I empty it manually?
4. What can I do in order to avoid purchasing more storage every month?

Update: it gets even more strange: I switched to full recovery model, took a full backup, took a log backup, and still the log will not truncate. Now the log data has gotten to 700GB with 2% free space in it. Nothing is using the DB - it has been isolated till I fix this problem. The log_reuse_wait_desc still stays on XCT_CHECKPOINT. Any explanations?

Comment: for starters, run `SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases;`.

Comment: right now it's on 'XCT_CHECKPOINT'. For more than 10h.

Comment: Is this a SQL Server 2014 database with a memory optimized filegroup?  What does DBCC OPENTRAN return?

Comment: 2014, yes. It does have a memory optimized filegroup, but it is not used. At all. DBCC OPENTRAN returns no active transaction.